# the most safe way to swap two class instance

Tags: c++, swap

Use `swap` to swap two class instances, sometimes it might throw errors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#include <cstring>
class Buffer {
public:
    Buffer(const string& s): buffer(s) {}
    string buffer;
};

template<class _Tx>
void SWAP(_Tx& a, _Tx& b) {
    size_t size = sizeof(_Tx);
    char buffer[size];
    memcpy(buffer, &a, size);
    memcpy(&a, &b, size);
    memcpy(&b, buffer, size);
}

int main() {
    Buffer a("This is a"), b("This is b");
    swap(a,b);
    cout << a.buffer << endl;

    SWAP(a,b);
    cout << b.buffer << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

the `std::swap` will do something like this:

```
template<class _Tx>
void swap(_Tx &a, _Tx &b) {
    _Tx t = a;
    a = b;
    b = t;
}
```

`_Tx t = a;` will call the copy constructor of `_Tx`, which is `Buffer::Buffer(Buffer &e)` in this case. This method try to allocate some memory, and this might cause some errors.

I try to use another method instead of `std::swap`:

```
template<class _Tx>
void SWAP(_Tx& a, _Tx& b) {
    char buffer[sizeof(_Tx)];
    memcpy(buffer, &a, sizeof(_Tx));
    memcpy(&a, &b, sizeof(_Tx));
    memcpy(&b, buffer, sizeof(_Tx));
}
```

Is it a safe way ???

**UPDATES**
`std::swap` might be safe with c++0x. This is the comparison: [c99](http://ideone.com/Jo6vOH) vs. [c++0x](http://ideone.com/PJX2BL)

---

**REF** 
[what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) *Thanks Donal Fellows's remind*

Comment: re `memcpy` no, absoutely not.

Comment: Of course using `memcpy` on non-trivial types is much safer than goold old `std::swap` (I hope you won't mind the sarcasm ;)).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the copy-and-swap idiom?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the  dynamic allocated pointer `buffer`, why don't you use `std::string` instead

copy constructor signature is:

```
Buffer(const Buffer &e)
```

now you swap the objects:

```
int main(int agrc, char* argv[])
{
  Buffer a("This is a"), b("This is b");
  std::swap(a,b);
}
```

std::swap code shall be faster than your SWAP code

```
template<class _Ty> inline
void swap(_Ty& _Left, _Ty& _Right)
{   // exchange values stored at _Left and _Right
  _Ty _Tmp = _Move(_Left);
  _Left = _Move(_Right);
  _Right = _Move(_Tmp);
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's the point. If `string` is embedded in the `Buffer` , the `std::swap(Buffer &, Buffer &)` will not use the specialized `string::swap` to avoid reallocation of the `string` field, so there still might be a problem.

Comment: @idy you don't need your SWAP anymore, just use std::swap

Comment: @billz but `std::swap` will call the `string(const string& str)` to do the assignment. The string's assignment method will dynamic alloc memory.

Comment: I think std::swap is faster than you SWAP?

Comment: @billz It dependences on the member's assignment constructor??? `std::swap` need three times of assignment.

Comment: it's using move semantics, which only moves the pointer around. unless I am wrong.

Comment: @billz [sample@ideone](http://ideone.com/Jo6vOH) `std::swap` actually called the assignment constructor of `Inner` class.

Comment: Not if you define `Buffer& operator=(Buffer&& b)`

Comment: @idy Of course using const rvlaue references is pretty useless and in fact doesn't give you a move constructor at all. And I guess the compiler used by ideone is not good at automatically generating move members.

Answer (score 0):

It will work for this particular Buffer object but may not be safe at all if it evolves of if you use it with another class. It's the role of the assignment operator and/or copy constructor of the class to make it safe.